# Power Automate e sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Como criar um fluxo que espera o fcheiro ser editado e depois faz a leitura.

Tentei usar o "When a file is created ou modified" ele executa em cada alteração.

O fciheiro vai ser alterado em mais de um campo

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Quero fazer um fluxo que quando o ficheiro é modificado ele dispara . Mas só que isso tem que ser feito na quinta feira em um especifico horario .  O ficheiro está no sharepoint